# An error in Dymola "Failed to generate XML file for the FMU"?

Tags: modelica, dymola

A model works fine, but on my PC it ends up with an error "Failed to generate XML file for the FMU".
Someone told me this is because the XML parser is broken on Windows system. Anyone know the exact reason for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Someone tells me that this could be caused by XML parser in the Windows system is broken. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: Here is the download link https://github.com/alex19941215/ThermoSysPro         There is a ThermoSysPro.zip that includes the ThermoSysPro library, my test example is TestStodolaTurbine3.mo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the logic to avoid generating that error, and the error message has been improved in later versions of Dymola.
In Dymola 2020x you get:

> Failed to generate XML file for the FMU or for variable dependencies.

indicating that the issue is likely that you have set `Advanced.GenerateVariableDependencies=true;`

Comment: Obvious follow-up question: why does it fail to generate the dependencies?

Comment: @matth I'm looking at that, one issue is that it is a completely static model - but there might be more.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue when exporting an FMU. For me the above listed options didn't work but excluding the auxiliary variables worked. Might be an really specific solution but  I wanted to share it anyway.
The corresponding command in Dymola is `Advanced.FMI.xmlIgnoreLocal = true`
A screenshot of the settings can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZsYG.png)

Answer (score 3):

FMUs are causal, so you have to use causal inputs and outputs as interfaces. These inputs must be defined at the top level, so Dymola knows what the interfaces of the FMU to export will be.

In your model the inputs of some components are open. You have to define top-level connectors for them and connect them, like in the screenshot below. Then the FMU export will work.

[image: Screenshot of model for FMU export, with inputs connected]

The same goes for outputs: If your FMU shall have outputs, you must define them on top level. In your example we can easily do that for `stodolaTurbine.MechPower`.

Comment: But I didn't try to export FMU, I only tried to do simulation. This model doesn't work on my computer, but it works on my colleague's computer. So, I am thinking about if my setting in dymola is wrong?

Comment: Your error message indicates, that you tried to generate a FMU. It will not appear in regular simulations. Simulation of the model works, but Dymola will use 0 for all open inputs.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Guess my Dymola installation or OS is broken. I will re-install Dymola. I would update the question if there is any progress.

Comment: Generation of modelDescription.xml can be truned on independently of fmu generation using the flag `Advanced.FMI.GenerateModelDescriptionInterface2`. What value does that flag have for you?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me the error popped up when I had the combination of the two flags:

- „Translation“ -> „Provide variable dependencies for plotting“ (which
  is Advanced.GenerateVariableDependencies) = true.
- „FMI Export“ -> “Exclude Auxiliary variables“ (which is
  Advanced.FMI.xmlIgnoreLocal) = true.

Disabeling one of them both got rid of the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

The explanations from macro and Hans Olsson are very helpful. Thanks to their help I found the reason. It is because I set "Provide variable dependencies for plotting" in the Translation Tab.

[image]

[image]